# Пустое значение поля в yaml

Tags: php, symfony, yaml

Я хочу оставить значение поля в моём `.yaml` - файле пустым.
Просто в одном переводе данное поле должно быть заполнено, а в другом нет.

Если данное поле не определить, то на фронте будет выведен путь к его значению (`...title.3`).

Должен, наверное, быть какой-то способ.

**Хотелось бы что-то подобное:**

```yaml
title:
    1: String
    2: String2
    3:
```

---

**Отсюда вопрос**:
можно ли в `yaml` как-то установить пустое значение в поле и если можно, то как?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34089496/empty-field-in-yaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, конечно.
В `yaml` есть возможность установить в поле пустое значение.
Вы можете использовать для этого тильду(<kbd>~</kbd>) или `null`.

Все это можно прочитать в [документации YAML](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html) и в [описании формата Yaml в Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml/yaml_format.html#nulls).

**Пример:**

```yaml
title:
    1: String
    2: String2
    3: ~
```

---

**Ссылки:**

- Документация YAML
  http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html
- Описание поддерживаемого формата Yaml в Symfony
  http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml/yaml_format.html#nulls

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34089604/4558866